# Standard for labelling align environment

Tags: align, labels

Is there a standard for referencing equations in an align environment 'collectively'? Meaning that there is one global label along with all the individual labels as in

```
  \begin{align} % \label{eq:abcd}
      a &= b \label{eq:ab} \\
      c &= d \label{eq:cd}
  \end{align}
  % \ref{eq:abcd} will fail
```

I would like `Eqs.\ref{eq:abcd}` to result in something like `Eqs.(1)-(2)` or similar. I am getting around this by using the below command for small align environments, but obviously it doesn't scale up very well.

```
\newcommand{\alref}[2]{Eqs.~(\ref{#1})-(\ref{#2})}
```

If individual labels are listed as `1a)`, `1b)` and so on, then I would also be happy with `\ref{eq:abcd}` resulting in `1`, say.

Comment: For the latter see the `subequations` env from `amsmath` it is described in the `amsmath` manual https://texdoc.org/serve/amsmath/0 section 3.11.3